# ETL process with Npgsql source suddenly started crashing

Tags: ssis, npgsql

[ADO NET Source [2]] Error: Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

connection string like:
Host=xxx;Database=xxx;Username=xxx;Port=xxx;Command Timeout=0;Timeout=0;Pooling=True;Internal Command Timeout=0;Connection Pruning Interval=300;No Reset On Close=False;Use Perf Counters=False;

Answer (score 0):

After noticing some regularity, setting CommandTimeout=0 in SSIS on source helped.
[image]